# how to get 2 select option dropdown from database using while in jsp mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

```
    /*connection query here*/
  <select>
     <%while(rs.next())
       {%>
            <option><%= rs.getString("column_1")%></option>
      <%}%>
     </select>

       <select>
         <%while(rs.next())
           {%>
                <option><%= rs.getString("column_2")%></option>
            <%}%>
       </select>
```

i want to show two different column data as two different drop down in same jsp

Comment: very less information is provided describing the problem....

Comment: simple i want to use two table column data as two different drop down field in jsp mysql  using while statement it running and created select field also

Comment: so what doesn't work ? did you got any error ?

Comment: no i did't receive any error

Answer (score 0):

You Details are very short and  I think My Attachment Reference link solve your problem.

[External reference](https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/jsp/how-to-create-dynamic-drop-down-list-in-jsp-from-database)

Answer (score 0):

<%
ResultSet rs=stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

```
    while(rs.next())
    {   %>
            <option value="<%=rs.getString("column1")%>"><%=rs.getString("column1") %></option>
    <% }
 <%
ResultSet rs1=stmt1.executeQuery(sql);

    while(rs1.next())
    {   %>
            <option value="<%=rs1.getString("column2")%>"><%=rs1.getString("column2") %></option>
    <% }
```

use 2 result set for use two while statement in same jsp page, better solution welcomed thanks.... for all